# Active Class only works on first element

Tags: jquery

I have the following list in a page:

```
        <ul id="gallery-list" class="gallery-list">
     <li>   <a class="gallery-link" href="fullurl/galleries/?phpvar=front-steps" id="Front"><h3>Front Steps Project</h3></a></li>
        <li>   <a class="gallery-link" href="fullurl/galleries?phpvar=cake-smash" id="Cake"><h3>Cake Smash</h3></a></li>
       <li>    <a class="gallery-link" href="fullurl/galleries?phpvar=big-kids" id="Big"><h3>Big Kids</h3></a></li>
        <li>   <a class="gallery-link" href="fullurl/galleries?phpvar=bumps" id="Bumps"><h3>Bumps</h3></a></li>
       <li>    <a class="gallery-link" href="fullurl/galleries?phpvar=newborn" id="Newborn"><h3>Newborn</h3></a></li>
       <li>    <a class="gallery-link" href="fullurl/galleries?phpvar=boys" id="Boys"><h3>Boys</h3></a></li>
       <li>    <a class="gallery-link" href="fullurl/galleries?phpvar=girls" id="Girls"><h3>Girls</h3></a></li>
        <li>   <a class="gallery-link" href="fullurl/galleries?phpvar=siblings" id="Siblings"><h3>Siblings</h3></a></li>
       <li>    <a class="gallery-link" href="fullurl/galleries?phpvar=families"  id="Families"><h3>Families</h3></a></li>
        </ul>
```

I used the following jQuery to add an active class based on if the href of the link was the same as the url:

```
  var current = location.href;
$('#gallery-list li a').each(function(){
 if (this.href === current) {
   $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

However it's only adding the active class if you click the first list item. How do I get the active class to work on all links?

Comment: Does each link load a new page or do you have other code that intercepts the clicks and uses ajax?

Answer (score 0):

I've created a snippet which works according to your need. I've explained the code wherever necessary. Hope it helps you.

```js
$(function() {

  const current = location.href;  // get the current full url
 
 $('.gallery-link').each(function() { // loop through all elements with class {gallery-link}
    
    let $this = $(this);  // current element(so that element is same in scope change)
    
    if ($this.attr('href') === current) { // check attribute {href} 
      
      $this.addClass('active'); // if yes, add class {active}
    
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="gallery-list" class="gallery-list">
  <li>
    <a class="gallery-link" href="fullurl/galleries/?phpvar=front-steps" id="Front">
      <h3>Front Steps Project</h3>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="gallery-link" href="fullurl/galleries?phpvar=cake-smash" id="Cake">
      <h3>Cake Smash</h3>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="gallery-link" href="fullurl/galleries?phpvar=big-kids" id="Big">
      <h3>Big Kids</h3>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="gallery-link" href="fullurl/galleries?phpvar=bumps" id="Bumps">
      <h3>Bumps</h3>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="gallery-link" href="fullurl/galleries?phpvar=newborn" id="Newborn">
      <h3>Newborn</h3>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="gallery-link" href="fullurl/galleries?phpvar=boys" id="Boys">
      <h3>Boys</h3>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="gallery-link" href="fullurl/galleries?phpvar=girls" id="Girls">
      <h3>Girls</h3>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="gallery-link" href="https://stacksnippets.net/js" id="Siblings"><!-- href of current snippet -->
      <h3>Siblings</h3>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="gallery-link" href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61701723/active-class-only-works-on-first-element" id="Families"><!-- href of current page -->
      <h3>Families</h3>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This shouldn't work since the href ***attributes*** are relative whereas `location.href` is absolute

Comment: he wrote full-url in the href, i'm assuming he didn't want to reveal full url.

Comment: Ahh yes, I missed that. But OP approach using `this.href` should work fine. An `<a>` element has an href property

Comment: I guess, it will. It's pretty much the same thing but as his tag was only jquery, so I altered it. :)

Comment: Sure but simply changing to using the attribute and jQuery doesn't explain why the original doesn't work...which it should assuming links load a new page each time

Comment: @charlietfl the links don't load a new page, they update the variable at the end of the url - is this why nothing I have tried will work?

Comment: if every link is updating the url then you'll have to fire this function `onclick` so that each time user clicks the link it checks the `url` and `href`.

Comment: Yes that would explain it. You need a click listener to modify them

Answer (score -1):

You can set pageUrl into hiddenfield from session variable on server-side.

Then using jquery .each() loop match current url and set active class, else remove it.

```
setActiveMenus();

function setActiveMenus() {

    var getCurUrl = $("#hiddenfieldPageUrl").val();
   
    $("#gallery-list li a").each(function () {
        var self = $(this);
        var selfUrl = self.attr('href');

        if (selfUrl == getCurUrl) {
            self.addClass("active");
           
        } else {
            self.removeClass("active");
        }

    });

}
```

---

If full url is available on anchor tag.
Then below code will work fine, that is loop over anchor tag by classname.

```
 var current = location.href ;
$('#gallery-list .gallery-link').each(function() {
    var self = $(this);
    var aURL = self.attr("href");
    if (aURL == current) {
        self.addClass('active');
    } else {
        self.removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

Comment: What's wrong with matching `location.href`? This approach seems overly complex and doesn't explain why OP approach doesn't work

Comment: @charlietfl: using location.href will give full URL of the page, including the protocol (like http://) . Here in html anchor tag contains only Controller action with query string not full url (https://......)

Comment: OP has used an alias "fullurl" to sanitize with

Comment: OK but OP's `this.href` returns  same as `$(this).attr('href')` when an absolute url is used in href attribute....so none of this explains why Op code won't work

Comment: this.href gives the absolute URI, where as $(this).attr("href") gives exact value of the href property which may or may not be a relative URI. Maybe op has not set full url, hence the code is not working for him. As he is checking againt absolue url

Comment: As I mentioned that is not relevant when `"fullurl" makes it absolute and also wouldn't explain why it does work on the first one

Comment: I tried this code but it doesn't work, would it be because the links reload the same page but with a different gallery? I'm using the url's to tell the page which gallery to load. this and also the answer below do the same as my original code?